# SQL Server : SELECT Highest Price and add qty's from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table `TableAllProds`:

```
ProdName      ManuPartNo   Price    Qty   Supplier
--------------------------------------------------
Part1         R10001       100.00    2     Supp1
Part2         R10002       500.00    2     Supp2
Part3         R30023        50.00    1     Supp3
Part2again    R10002       100.00    5     Supp4
Part2Again    R10002       300.00   10     Supp5
Part1again    R10001       200.00    5     Supp3
```

I have a select statement to bring me back the highest price which works fine if there are duplicate products from different suppliers.

```
SELECT 
    ProdName, ManuPartNo, Price, Qty, Supplier
FROM
    (SELECT 
         dbo.TableAllProds.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ManuPartNo ORDER BY Price ASC) AS RN
     FROM 
         dbo.TableAllProds) AS t
WHERE 
    RN = 1
ORDER BY 
    ManuPartNo
```

However I would also like to total all of the qty's for all suppliers Example for ManuPartNo - R10001 I would Like to return R10001 - 200.00 - 7(qty) and the supplier of the highest Price if possible.

Not sure how to google this, I can either return the highest/Lowest price easily and also return a sum of the qty for each part but am not sure about how to perform both queries at once.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do it as a derived table to get the total of the part and then join it back over on the ManuPartNo

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUM` as a windowed function:

```
SELECT ProdName, ManuPartNo, Price, Qty, TotalQty, Supplier
FROM (  SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo ORDER BY Price ASC) AS RN,
               SUM(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo) AS TotalQty,
        FROM dbo.TableAllProds) AS t
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ManuPartNo;
```

Comment: Lamak this worked perfectly, thankyou very much.  I will use this in a few places wasnt sure where to start, (Also Learned about derived tables, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you want... uncomment the where clause if you only want that supplier.

```
declare @TableAllProds table (ProdName varchar(16), ManuPartNo varchar(16), Price decimal (5,2), Qty int, Supplier varchar(16))
insert into @TableAllProds
values
('Part1','R10001',100.00,2,'Supp1'),
('Part2','R10002',500.00,2,'Supp2'),
('Part3','R30023',50.00,1,'Supp3'),
('Part2again','R10002',100.00,5,'Supp4'),
('Part2Again','R10002',300.00,10,'Supp5'),
('Part1again','R10001',200.00,5,'Supp3')

;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
    ProdName, 
    ManuPartNo, 
    Price, 
    Supplier,
    sum(Qty) over (partition by ManuPartNo) TotalOverAllSuppliers, 
    case when Price = max(price) over (partition by ManuPartNo) then Supplier end HighestPricedSupplier
FROM
    @TableAllProds)

select
*
from cte
--where HighestPricedSupplier is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.ManuPartNo, a.Price, a.QTY, b.Supplier
FROM (SELECT t1.ManuPartNo, MAX(t1.Price) AS Price, SUM(t1.Qty) AS QTY
      FROM dbo.alltableprods t1
      GROUP BY t1.ManuPartNo) a
JOIN (SELECT t2.ManuPartNo, t2.price, T2.Supplier,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ManuPartNo ORDER BY t2.price desc) 
      AS RN
      FROM dbo.alltableprods t2
      GROUP BY t2.ManuPartNo, t2.Price, t2.Supplier) b ON a.ManuPartNo = 
b.ManuPartNo
WHERE b.RN = 1
```

Using this will return

```
R10001  200.00  7   Supp3
R10002  500.00  17  Supp2
R30023  50.00   1   Supp3
```

I have a question though. Is it possible for there to be more than one supplier that has the same part at the same price? If so then this will still work however it will just grab whatever applicable supplier it finds first.

Comment: thanks all for the comments, all have tought me a bit and its good to see different approaches to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can query using row_number as below:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(Partition by ManuPartNo order by Price desc),  SmQty = Sum(Qty) over(Partition by ManuPartNo) from dbo.TableAllProds ) a
   where a.RowN = 1
```