# SQL SERVER Case Statement for Order By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following on from my earlier question of if I can bring back the highest price and also total all quantities from multiple suppliers [Select Highest Price and add Qty's for all suppliers] ([SQL Server : SELECT Highest Price and add qty's from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571157/sql-server-select-highest-price-and-add-qtys-from-table))

I would like to put a case statement into the ORDER BY Price DESC part of the query to return the highest Price if the qty is > 10 or return the lowest if the case is not met, but I cant seem to get the query to work.  Is it possible to put a case in the same query? or is there another way to go about this?.

This works fine as it is

```
SELECT ManuPartNo, WebPrice, TotalQtyAdded, Supplier
FROM
(SELECT dbo.TableAllProds. *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo ORDER BY WebPrice DESC) AS RN,
    SUM(TotalQty) OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo) AS TotalQtyAdded
        FROM TableAllProds) AS t
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ManuPartNo
```

This is what I have been trying but however I seem to write the If part it doesn't seem to like the syntax.

```
SELECT ProdName, ManuPartNo, Price, Qty, TotalQty, Supplier
FROM (  SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo 
               ORDER BY 
                      CASE WHEN Price > '10' Price DESC
                      ELSE Price ASC END ) AS RN,
           SUM(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo) AS TotalQty,
    FROM dbo.TableAllProds) AS t
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ManuPartNo;
```

Is it possible to write this in one query? any suggestions or pointers to other posts would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot mixing sorting together. `DESC` and `ASC` cannot be part of expression.

Comment: (1) There is no `case` _statement_, but there is a `case` _expression_. (B) You probably meant `when Qty > 10`, not `when Price > 10`. (iii) Although a `case` expression can't return a sort order, you can do odd things like `order by case when Qty > 10 then -Price else Price end`. That will flip the order depending on the `Qty`. (d) Stop mixing numbers and strings. `10` is a number, `'10'` is a string. If you want to compare `Price` or `Qty` to a number then use a number.

Comment: HABO thanks, I was mixing up price and qty in the case, Also changing the strings to numbers made the statement work but it didn't bring back the results I wanted. It is late now. I shall post up some content and expected results and reformat my question.  I can using ssis split the highest and lowest price into temp tables then based on qty choose either the highest or lowest, add all qty's again Into another temp table then bring back the data into a single table and update the total quantities, I was just not sure how do this in one single select query.

Comment: Sorry just noted the - before the price. Should that return the lower value ?

Comment: @JohnSpencer If you sort by `Price` (ascending) you'll get the lowest price first. Sort by the negative of `Price` and the first value will be the largest value which becomes the most negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WITH TIES` clause.

However, the sub-query WHERE RN=1 is a nudge more performant

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  dbo.TableAllProds
 Order By row_number() over (partition by ManuPartNo Order by try_convert(money,Price) Desc)
```

Comment: Hi John thanks for your answer I tried this however I am not sure where I would state my minimum qty ie >10 to then choose either highest or lowest if it met the condition.